# Не вводит информация в базу данных с формы

Tags: php, mysql

**Вот код:** 
if (isset($_POST['city']))
{
    $city = ($_POST['city']);
    $city = $city;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'";
if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)))
{
    queryMysql("UPDATE profiles SET user='$user' 
                where city='$city'");
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO profiles VALUES('$user', '$name', '$surname', '$city', '$age', '$site', '$icq', '$skype', '$vk', '$twit', '$about')";
    queryMysql($query);
}
```

}
else
{
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'";
    $result = queryMysql($query);

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $row  = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $city = $row[3];
}
else $city = "";
```

}

$city = $city;

**Вот код формы;**

```
< form method='post' action='profile.php'
    enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Имя: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='name' value='$name' /><br />
Фамилия: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='surname' value='$surname' /><br />
Город: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='city' value='$city' /><br />
Сайт: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='site' value='$site' /><br />
ICQ: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='icq' value='$icq' /><br />
Skype: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='skype' value='$skype' /><br />
ВКонтакте: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='vl' value='$vk' /><br />
Twitter: < input type='text' maxlength='64' name='twit' value='$twit' /><br />
Аватарка: < input type='file' name='image' size='14' maxlength='32' /><br />
< input type='submit' value='Сохранить' />
< /form>
```

**P.S. Другая информация вводится нормально, кроме этой**

Answer (score 1):

Учите синтаксис оператора

```
INSERT INTO profiles (`USER_COL`, `NAME_COL`) VALUES('$user', '$name')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryMysql ???
```

синтаксис учите. **mysql_query(QUERY);**

```
if (isset($_POST['city'])) { $city = ($_POST['city']); $city = $city;
```

зачем **$city = $city;**

```
 queryMysql("UPDATE profiles SET user='$user' 
            where city='".$city."'");
```